# How to define new operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to define a generic exponentiation operator that can be interfaced like this:

```
> 10^3         // 1000
> 2.71^2       // 7.3441
> 3.14^(-3.14) // 0.027..
```

According to the docs it's possible to extend classes with infix functions:

```
// Define extension to Int
infix fun Int.exp(exponent: Int): Int {
...
}
```

But they don't allow symbols like `^`

Comment: As an aside, even if it were possible define an exponent operator, I would recommend against using `^`. In Java, C#, and many other languages, the `^` operator performs [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), so it would be surprising to see it do something different in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, `**` would probably be the safer choice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot define new operators, there's only a [predefined set](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) of those that can be overloaded. Some operators might be added to this set later, there's an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1440) for that in the Kotlin issue tracker.

However, you can use backticked names to define `infix` extension functions which look like operators (much less pretty though):

```
infix fun Int.`^`(exponent: Int): Int = ...
```

Usage:

```
5 `^` 3
```

Note that `infix` functions have precedence lower than that of operators, thus

```
1 + 1 `^` 3 == 8
```

Comment: all of the above, but "Fortunately"

Comment: I hope they consider consider adding a power operator, since it is widely used in any kind of math. `Math.pow` is a little bit clunky imo.

Comment: @TomTom you can do `2.0.pow(4)`. Pow is from kotlin.math

Answer (score 5):

I works with *Math*. *Android Studio* forbids to use `^` with quotes. 
So I've defined `v` operator (`^` upside down). Is it ugly?  Yes, but it is best than
thons of typecasting and `pow` notation.

```
inline infix fun Double.v(exponent: Int): Double = this.pow(exponent)
inline infix fun Double.v(exponent: Long): Double = this.pow(exponent.toDouble())
inline infix fun Double.v(exponent: Double): Double = this.pow(exponent)
inline infix fun Int.v(exponent: Int): Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent)
inline infix fun Int.v(exponent: Long): 
      Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent.toDouble())
inline infix fun Int.v(exponent: Double): Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent)
inline infix fun Long.v(exponent: Int): Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent)
inline infix fun Long.v(exponent: Long): 
      Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent.toDouble())
inline infix fun Long.v(exponent: Double): 
      Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent)
```

`inline` usage generates no extra load in runtime, even inside heavier loops.

Unfortunately, the damaged operator precedence forces you to surround the power operation with parentheses. And the compiler forces you flank with spaces.

After all, what gives the best look?

This?

```
var k=2  
...
println((k v 5)+3)
```

Or this?

```
var k=2
 ... 
println(k.toDouble().pow(5) + 3)
```

I vote on the fist option!.

Comment: Great!  and what about this?     inline infix fun <T : Number> T.v(exponent: T): Double = this.toDouble().pow(exponent.toDouble())

Comment: Yes! You are right. Great idea.I will change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

No. Kotlin only allows overloading a **predefined** set of operators, as indicated in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html). And `^` is not one of them (it's not even an operator AFAIK, so it can't be overloaded).